# Change temp working folder (tmp) with easy_install

Tags: python, easy-install

I am trying to install the birdsuite pipeline from the Broad Institute using the included easy install package.  The installation fails when trying to find a set up script:

```
=================================================================
SETTING UP http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/plinkpipeline/plinkpipeline-1.6.6-py2.5.egg
:
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/p/plinkpipeline/plinkpipeline-1.6.6-py2.5.egg

Processing plinkpipeline-1.6.6-py2.5.egg

error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install-hxr0WF/plinkpipeline-1.6.6-py2.5.egg

=================================================================
```

I agree with the error, I cannot find a script in the specified folder either.  I have permission to write files and folders in /tmp/.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that project provides *only* a python 2.5 egg, which does not include a setup.py file at all.

That is an error on the part of the author of the package. You need to find a `.tar.gz` source distribution instead. I cannot locate one, though.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. that is very helpful.  I cannot get in touch with the package's author either, his email address is no longer working.   I'll have to do some digging. Chers!